# Upload a file on AWS S3 using pre-signed URL in .NET 6 (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-6.0, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket using a pre-signed URL. I'm using the following code:

```
Uri output = GetPresignedUrl(amazonS3, awsPresignedUrlOptions);

using (FileStream tempInFileStream = new(tempFileName.LocalPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new())
    {
        StreamContent streamContent = new(tempInFileStream);
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient
            .PutAsync(output, streamContent)
            .Result;

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

The first line of code gets the pre-signed URL, and I'm sure it works because if I use the URL in Postman to try a PUT, it works fine (i.e., I'm able to upload the file).

My problem is in the `HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PutAsync(output, streamContent).Result;` line: executing the line, the software seems to do absolutely nothing and, after a period, raise an exception for the timeout.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Yevhen Cherkes, I tried to use async code:

```
private static async void UploadAsync(Uri tempFileName, Uri output)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream tempInFileStream = new(tempFileName.LocalPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new())
            {
                StreamContent streamContent = new(tempInFileStream);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient
                    .PutAsync(output, streamContent);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Called with this code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => UploadAsync(tempFileName, output));

t.Start();
t.Join();
```

The main thread correctly starts the sub-thread and waits to join, but when I tried to run the line `HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(output, streamContent);`, execution immediately jumps to the line after `t.Join();` with no errors or exceptions.

What can be done?

Regards.

Comment: It can be a deadlock caused by accessing Result value of async operation. Could you try to change it to async await?

Comment: I mean: var response = await httpClient
            .PutAsync(output, streamContent);

Comment: @YevhenCherkes, I just tried, no result... Please see my update question.

Comment: The asynchronous code should be not mixed with Multithreading,
Could you try the following changes?

static async Task UploadAsync(Uri tempFileName, Uri output)
...

await UploadAsync(tempFileName, output);

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Yenhen Cherkes for the suggestion. Following the code that works for me.

The method is very simple:

```
private static async Task UploadAsync(Uri tempFileName, Uri output)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(tempFileName.LocalPath))
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            StreamContent streamContent = new(fileStream);

            await httpClient.PutAsync(output, streamContent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

To call this method use:

```
output = GetPresignedUrl(amazonS3, awsPresignedUrlOptions);
await UploadAsync(tempFileName, output);
```

where `output` is the pre-signed URI and `tempFileName` is the URI to the local resource.

Comment: Your `catch` block is useless, you could remove the entire try/catch. And actually it's worse than useless, it removes the stack trace information from the Exception. At the very least, when re-throwing an exception, just use `throw;` instead of `throw e;`

Comment: Can't we use AWS SDK for this instead of HttpClient ?

Comment: @Niroshana if your client app has enough permissions to use AWS SDK for the upload, then why would you need a  presigned url?